# How to use selenium to click on a discord servers channel?

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to use selenium with python to automate some discord tasks. I have it open browser to discordapp.com, login, go to the server in question, but I can't find any css selector, xpath, class name, etc to be able to click on a channel called "commands". Any help would be appreciated.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\levir\OneDrive\Desktop\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://discordapp.com')
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('appButton-3GZ9-9') #login button
linkElem.click()
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/input')
linkElem.send_keys('EMAIL') #email
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/input')
linkElem.send_keys('PASSWORD') #password
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]/div')
linkElem.click() #logs in
time.sleep(10)
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]')
linkElem.click() #enters server
time.sleep(1)
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.containerDefault-1ZnADq:nth-child(4)')
linkElem.click() #is supposed to enter channel but doesn't work
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML or a set of demo credentials (EMAIL/PASSWORD)

Comment: You are doing everything right bro, If you wanna select a channel then you don't need to select channel with CSS, or Xpath, Just use the URL of the channel like browser.get('https://discordapp.com/channel url') if you are not getting it, just reply I will show you my code

Answer (score 3):

The channels items I tried to click on had a class name of "wrapper-1BJsBx" and a tag type of "a".
Maybe "1BJsBx" is an autogenerated suffix so I propose using regex to avoid lots of maintenance.
I could click on specific channel using the following:

```py
for elem in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class^=wrapper-]")
  if "my_awesome_channel_name" in elem.get_attribute('aria-label').lower():
    elem.click()
    break
```

using python3.7 and selenium 3.141.0

Comment: that does seem to work for me. It doesn't throw an error, but does interact with the webpage. a[class^=wrapper-1ucjTd] is the thing i used.

Answer (score 1):

The css selector is incorrect, go into the inspect panel, select the element, right click on it, select copy > copy selector and paste that selector

Answer (score 1):

Copy the Xpath of this line and you'll be able to click it im pretty sure

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import random
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
driver.get("https://discord.com/channels/191530268761260034/230742511235104769")
print(driver.title)
try:
    sold = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(

        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input'))
    )
except:
    pass
textName = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
textName.send_keys('Put_Email_Here')

textCode = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/input')
textCode.send_keys('Put_Code_Here')

#confirm button
confrim = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]').click()

#wating for the server to load
try:
    sold = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(

        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH,
             '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div[4]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div'))
    )
except:
    pass
    channel1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div[4]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div').click()
```